# How to Use UseEffect() Hook to Fetch State from Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to use React's useEffect() hook to access state from Redux to automatically fill out my form fields. I am calling the getCurrentProfile() action which returns an object called profile.

However, I am receiving an error message in the console saying that I am missing dependencies for the form fields that I am trying to update with state.

I've tried the following items:

1) Add each dependency listed in the error message. This gets rid of the error message, but useEffect() will keep firing off. I can see this because my Redux devtools shows my action being consistently called.

2) I've tried using the setState() hook outside of useEffect(), but I get an error since my Redux action gets called after the component is painted.

3) I am still new to React and I have spent hours trying to figure this out. I previously used getDerivedStateFromProps to solve this problem when I was using class components.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Or if you could point me to an appropriate resource then that will be great too. Thank you!

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();

    setFormData({
      company: loading || !profile.company ? '' : profile.company,
      website: loading || !profile.website ? '' : profile.website,
      location: loading || !profile.location ? '' : profile.location,
      status: loading || !profile.status ? '' : profile.status,
      skills: loading || !profile.skills ? '' : profile.skills.join(','),
      bio: loading || !profile.bio ? '' : profile.bio,
      githubusername:
        loading || !profile.githubusername ? '' : profile.githubusername,
      youtube: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.youtube,
      twitter: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.twitter,
      linkedin: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.linkedin,
      instagram: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.instagram,
      facebook: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.facebook
    });
  }, [loading, getCurrentProfile]);
```

Here is the error message.

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'profile.bio',
'profile.company', 'profile.githubusername', 'profile.location',
'profile.skills', 'profile.social', 'profile.status', and
'profile.website'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.
If 'setFormData' needs the current value of 'profile.company', you can
also switch to useReducer instead of useState and read
'profile.company' in the reducer  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is from devconnector 2 of brad traversy!, the fix here is just by adding those arguments to the use effect array at the end like this:

` useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();

```
setFormData({
  company: loading || !profile.company ? '' : profile.company,
  website: loading || !profile.website ? '' : profile.website,
  location: loading || !profile.location ? '' : profile.location,
  status: loading || !profile.status ? '' : profile.status,
  skills: loading || !profile.skills ? '' : profile.skills.join(','),
  githubusername:
    loading || !profile.githubusername ? '' : profile.githubusername,
  bio: loading || !profile.bio ? '' : profile.bio,
  twitter: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.twitter,
  facebook: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.facebook,
  linkedin: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.linkedin,
  youtube: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.youtube,
  instagram: loading || !profile.social ? '' : profile.social.instagram
});},[loading, getCurrentProfile, profile.bio, profile.company, profile.githubusername, profile.location, profile.skills, profile.social, profile.status, profile.website]); `
```

Comment: It is most definitely from Brad's MERN stack course. I can't add them as dependencies because they are null until getCurrentProfile() finishes running first. This causes a separate error of its own. I think this is why Brad didn't simply list them.

Comment: try removing all the users on your database and retest again!